# How to pass/manipulate location of the user using java/servlet/jsp

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, geolocation, location

For developing a web application I need the client current location.

After fetching the current location, I need to show him the nearest people around who have registered in the same application.

I am using the below HTML Geolocation to fetch the current location of the users.

```js
   <script>
       var x = document.getElementById("demo");
       function getLocation() {
       if (navigator.geolocation) {
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
       } else {
          x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
       } }
       function showPosition(position) {
       x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
       "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
       }
   </script>
```

I have two questions in total :

First, I am not able to pass this values to my servlet as this is assigned in javascript.I have seen a similar answer on SO to pass the values using input type="hidden" but it did not work.What are possible ways to handle this type of situation?

Second, again I need to manipulate the longitude and latitude values at the backend(Servlet).Which java API has anybody used for location-based calculation such as 'finding nearby location/people etc.

Also, let me know if there is any other way I can handle this problem on the client side only.

I observe people using JSON and mixture of java, etc to accomplish but could not get a solid example.

Thanks in advance...